# Read files in a directory with dot

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got an error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/webnet/certificates/domain.com.key' when i want to read a file with fs.readFileSync. The file is '/webnet/certificates/domain.com/ssl.key'. Can you help me?

Comment: Is the file inside of your node.js project or outside?

Comment: dots inside folder names are generally not a good idea.

Comment: I am stupid. This problem is solved. It was a little mistake in the filename. console.log is great :-) Thank you all

Answer (score -1):

'/webnet/certificates/domain.com.key'
'/webnet/certificates/domain.com/ssl.key'.

2 different file paths. Mistake?